# What is the accuracy majority class classifier?

Tags: machine-learning, classification

I have an SFrame and a model:

```
train_data,test_data = products.random_split(.8, seed=0)
selected_words_model = graphlab.logistic_classifier.create(train_data,
                                                     target='sentiment',
                                                     features=selected_words,
                                                     validation_set=test_data)
```

After computing the accuracy of the model with `selected_words_model.evaluate(test_data) I'm asked *"What is the accuracy majority class classifier on this task?"* Yet I don't even know what this "means accuracy majority class classifier", shouldn't it be *"accuracy **of the** majority class classifier"* ?

Here is [my attempt](https://github.com/antoinecomp/Machine-Learning-WASHINGTON-Course-1/blob/master/Week3/Analyzing%20product%20sentiment.ipynb).

All these materials come from [this coursera ML fundations course exercise](https://www.coursera.org/learn/ml-foundations/supplement/phb1M/reading-analyzing-product-sentiment-assignment).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I suspect you are right that there is a missing "of the," and that the "majority class classifier" is the classifier that predicts the majority class for every input. Such a classifier is useful as a baseline model, and is particularly important when using accuracy as your metric. This matches what your notebook comments in the next bullet, so that's likely what was intended.

Comment: Thank you ! That seems the most simple classification method ;) I still have one doube : how should I compare different learned models with the baseline approach where we are just predicting the majority class ? I tried a `selected_words_model.show(view='Evaluation')` but it still might depend on the threshold ?

Answer (score 0):

Naive classifiers, such as [picking at random or always picking the majority class](https://machinelearningmastery.com/how-to-develop-and-evaluate-naive-classifier-strategies-using-probability/), serve as a braindead baseline to compare your model against. Hopefully your model can out-perform a naive model that simply randomly picks the response from the input rows, or doesn't look at the predictors at all!

It is also a warning about using metrics like accuracy for unbalanced datasets, ex. a dataset with response 90% 0s will give a majority classifier a 90% accuracy.

The majority classifier is in fact the optimal Bayes classifier assuming a prior based on the training class proportion, without looking at the predictor variables (so $Y$ and $X$ are independent):

$$
\hat y = \operatorname{argmax}_y P(y \mid \mathbf x) = \operatorname{argmax}_y P(y)
$$